# choose account in outlook when send mail via excel vba

Tags: vba, outlook, mail-sender

I want to send mails from a specific account in outlook from VBA in excel and Im stuck with my code, i went over and over the forums but it still doesnt work

I show you my code if anyone could help me it would be very very nice

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim signature As String
Dim LstRow As Long
LstRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account

For Each oAccount In Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts

If oAccount = "mymail@server.com" Then

For Each cell In ws.Range("A4:A" & LstRow)

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
signature = objMail.Body
    With objMail
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .Body = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & vbNewLine & signature
        .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = "15/03/2018 10:00:00 PM"
        .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
        .send
    End With

    Set objMail = Nothing
Next cell
Else
End If

Next
Set ws = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line you are getting error? did you try `.SentOnBehalfOfName` ?

Comment: There is no errors, juste the nail is not sent

Comment: Yes I also tried senton behalf but it is the same thing

Comment: Where is `.Send`  Or `.Display`?

Comment: sorry, it just after send using account

Comment: this line is weird also because it go through even if the account does not exist 'If oAccount = "mymail@server.com" Then'

Comment: comment this line `.DeferredDeliveryTime = "15/03/2018 10:00:00 PM"` and then run.

Comment: Now it sending but not with the good account..

Comment: good account means?

Comment: I have two account in outlook, the default one and "mymail@server.com" and i want the mail to be send from "mymail@server.com"

Comment: now try `.SentOnBehalfOfName`

Comment: Still sending with the default account..

Comment: I FIND THE SOLUTION :)

Comment: I need to add set in front of .sendUsingAccount

Comment: are you using Outlook 2016?

Comment: yes I use outlook 2016

Comment: :) great !!!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is just to put Set in front of .SendUsingAccount

```
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
signature = objMail.Body
   With objMail
    .To = cell.Value
    .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    .Body = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & vbNewLine & signature
    .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    .DeferredDeliveryTime = "15/03/2018 10:00:00 PM" 'need to comment here to run better
   Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount
    .send
End With
```

And also Thanks to Maddy i commented after the deferredDeliveryTime and it went well through the oAccount

Comment: `Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount` did not work, but `SentOnBehalfOfName` worked for me for `O365PP` for sending from another mailbox not my default one.