# Selecting right mailbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

In Outlook, I have two accounts configured:

1. my main account / inbox: chip@mail.com
2. a shared mailbox: shared@mail.com

So there are two different mailboxes.

I hid some default folders in both mailboxes, using VBA.

I want to unhide a default folder in the shared mailbox shared@mail.com.

This is the suggested code:

```vb
Option Explicit
  
Public Sub UnHideFolders()

Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oPA As Outlook.propertyAccessor
Dim PropName, Value, FolderType As String

PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"
Value = False
 
Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)

Set oPA = oFolder.propertyAccessor

oPA.SetProperty PropName, Value
 
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oPA = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works for the first mailbox account / inbox chip@mail.com.

How do I unhide folders in the second account / shared mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used for getting the folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Notes folder for the user who is currently logged on:

```
Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
```

To get folders from a shared account you need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder). The following code illustrates a possible usage of the method to get a shared calendar folder:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("shared@mail.com") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Note, the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method accepts the name of the recipient - it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

If that is not a standard folder or visible in Outlook you may consider using the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply & your support.
I couldn't manage to get it work, because the actual hidden folder to be unhiden is SyncIssues.
How should I change your code to get it work for that folder?

Comment: You can pass one of the [OlDefaultFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) enum values to the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method.

Comment: So the line would be just:
Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderSyncIssues) 

There hasn't be to changed anything more?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the required folder.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder, try

```
Set oFolder = Session.Accounts("shared@mail.com").DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
```

... then re-use your existing code to manage the folder.

Comment: That is valid for regular accounts configured in Outlook only, but not shared ones.

Comment: Doh! Read the question, John. @EugeneAstafiev At the risk of downvotes, I'll leave the answer here as 'mistake to avoid'!

Comment: @JohnM You're my hero! You made my day!
It worked like a charm!
Problem is solved right now. Where have you been in the last 11 hours? ;-) I'd have slept much better. :)

Comment: The accounts versus mailboxes issue is due to Microsoft using the word account for mailbox/email address in UI documentation. VBA is stricter. Without having the OP prove they know the difference, a response for either an account or a mailbox could benefit the OP or subsequent searchers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361724/1571407