Issues with Sending Email from Selected Account and Sending Without Displaying in Outlook VBA
I'm encountering two issues with my Outlook VBA code:

Multiple Accounts Issue: I have several accounts in Outlook, but when a different account is selected, the email still gets sent from the default account instead of the selected one. I'm trying to ensure that the email is sent from the currently active/selected account, but the "From" field is being pre-populated with the default account.

Send Without Display: The email can only be sent if I first call .Display, but I would like to send it directly without displaying the email window. If I omit .Display, the email doesn't send.


Here's the relevant portion of my code:
Private Sub GenerateCMD_Click()

    'If ValidateForm <> "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_PATH As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim File As Object
    Dim supplierNumber As String
    Dim emailAddress As String
    Dim splitName As Variant
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Dim subjectText As String
    
    Dim activeAccount As Object
    Dim DraftFolder As Object
    Dim SelectedAccountStore As Object
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim ToRecipient As Variant
    Dim olNamespace As Object
    Dim ActiveExplorer As Object
    Dim CurrentStore As Object
    Dim acct As Object
    
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNamespace = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ActiveExplorer = OlApp.ActiveExplorer
    
    If ActiveExplorer Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No active Outlook window detected.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set CurrentStore = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Store

    For Each acct In olNamespace.Accounts
        If acct.DeliveryStore = CurrentStore Then
            Set activeAccount = acct
            Exit For
        End If
    Next acct

    If activeAccount Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No active account found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set DraftFolder = activeAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
    
    ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_PATH = ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER
    
    subjectText = Me.Subject_Input.Text
    
    If Dir(ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_PATH, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_PATH & " NOT FOUND!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    If Len(subjectText) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Subject - NOT FOUND!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set WdDoc = wdApp.documents.Open(wd_Path)
        WdDoc.Content.Copy
        WdDoc.Close False
    Set WdDoc = Nothing
    
    If Not wdApp Is Nothing Then
        wdApp.Quit False
        Set wdApp = Nothing
    End If
    
    
'    Set WdRange = WdDoc.Content
'    'WdRange.Select
'    HtmlContent = WdRange.WordOpenXML
    
    Get_xlDate
    Unload Me
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(ATTACHMENTS_FOLDER_PATH)
        
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        splitName = Split(FSO.GetBaseName(File.Name), "_")
        supplierNumber = splitName(0)
        
        If Dict.Exists(supplierNumber) Then
            emailAddress = Dict(supplierNumber)
                
            Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            
            With OlMail
                .SendUsingAccount = activeAccount
                .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste
                .To = emailAddress
                .Subject = subjectText
                .Attachments.Add File.Path
                
               ' GetUserSelectedInput (.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress)
                
                '.HTMLBody = HtmlContent
                '.SaveSentMessageFolder = sentFolder
                '.SaveSentMessageFolder = activeAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(5)
                
                
                If oSend Then
                    .Display
                    .Send
                Else
                    .Move DraftFolder
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next File
    
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing
    Set OlMail = Nothing
    
End Sub


Are you creating a new Outlook instance? Maybe this is why the wrong account is selected.

can you propose a right code? Please

Are you calling your macro from outlook? If so try to replace CreateObject("Outlook.Application") with Outlook.Application

if the code is in Outlook then no need for "OlApp" just use = Application.ActiveExplorer or = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Possibly Set .SendUsingAccount = activeAccount rather than .SendUsingAccount = activeAccount. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295235/choose-account-in-outlook-when-send-mail-via-excel-vba. If not edit the question. Start with Option Explicit. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
